# variable might not been initialized from Scanner?

Tags: java, while-loop, try-catch, java.util.scanner

i declared the `Scanner infil`e before the `try-exception` but for some reason it says varible might not been initialized?

```
Scanner infile;
        try 
        {
            infile = new Scanner(file);
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException f)
        {
            System.out.println("Wrong File Path");
        }

        while (infile.hasNext())
        {
           System.out.print("Testing While loop");
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider what happens if an exception is thrown in the `new Scanner` constructor call. The constructor never completes, and so `new Scanner(file)` doesn't result in a value; what then for `infile`?

To correct it, move your `while` loop *into* the `try` block:

```
Scanner infile;
try 
{
    infile = new Scanner(file);

    while (infile.hasNext())
    {
       System.out.print("Testing While loop");
    }
}
catch(FileNotFoundException f)
{
    System.out.println("Wrong File Path");
}
```

The purpose of exception handling, after all, is to get it out of the way of your main logic.

Comment: But i will use constructors at the end. moving the `while` loop inside and declaring constructors inside `try` will cause a lot of errors and more complex programming. right ? @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @DkgMarine: No. By putting a `try` around *all* your logic and handling exceptions at the end, you make things *less* complicated, not more. But you do have a choice: If you don't want to put your logic inside the `try` (which is best practice), you could set `infile = null` in the `catch` block and then change the loop to `while (infile != null && infile.hasNext())`. But again, not best practices. You might find the [Java tutorial on exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) useful.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine the situation where `infile = new Scanner(file);` throws an Exception. At the point of `while (infile.hasNext())`, `infile` would not have been initialised.

You can solve this problem by just changing `Scanner infile;` for `Scanner infile = null;`. But be aware that `infile` can still be null at this point if the said exception is thrown. You should put that part of the code inside the `try` block.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to fix this would be to use Java's built in class error handling.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner infile;
    try {
        infile = new Scanner(new File("filename.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException f) {
        System.out.println("Wrong File Path");
    }

    while (infile.hasNext()) {
        System.out.print("Testing While loop");
    }
}
```

This code will not compile because there is a possibility that the file will not be found and the error is not handled, but if you add `throws FileNotFoundException` to the main function declaration, the exception will be handled by the main function and won't cause any problems.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
    Scanner infile;
    infile = new Scanner(new File("filename.txt"));
    
    while (infile.hasNext()) {
        System.out.print("Testing While loop");
    }
}
```

Sorry if my explanation isn't very good, I'm only just starting out with Java myself.